# Possible causes for large drop in measured firewall throughput

Tags: linux, firewall, monitoring, munin

We run our application on ec2 and use Munin to monitor various metrics. We do a bi-weekly fresh deploy on new ec2 + rds instances. After our most recent fresh deploy, we noticed a 4x reduction in the rate packets are coming through our firewall, but only on **one** of two servers. The odd thing is that the eth0 traffic bits per second measurement is normal for both machines.

What could cause a drop in the number of packets sent for the same number of bits in/out?

System details: We have two load-balanced application servers in different AWS availability zones, both running Ubuntu 10.04. The majority of our network I/O is caused by search indexing (triggered) via cron, where the app server pulls in a large amount of data from the database.

Here are the graphs for the first app server. The new instance started graphing at ~9:30pm on the 27th, exactly when the firewall throughput drops.[image: app0 firewall throughput][image: app0 eth0 traffic]

And the unaffected app server for comparison: [image: app1 firewall throughput][image: app1 eth0 traffic]

Answer (score 0):

Could the one server be configured to use a larger packet size?

Comment: sudo netstat -i eth0 shows the MTU as 1500 for both